# Union being overridden in OBIEE

Tags: mysql, obiee

I have used a 'Union' to combine two reports showing different dates. When I open the report on it's own it works fine with the two dates shown. However when I drill to the (union) report from another on the dashboard it only shows one date. Is there a dashboard filter that I may need to un apply or is there some other explanation!? I cannot seem to get the report to function as required from the drill.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511041/union-specific-override-in-obiee

Answer (score 0):

Tough to answer - need more info.  Some possibilities:

1. You're not really drilling to the report you think you are. You can learn a lot by looking at the log to see what's happening in the target report.
2. You may be passing values from the first report that exclude the date in the second report. Check your filters in the target report.  Look at the generated WHERE clause in the log. Run the SQL directly against the database. Is the date still excluded?

Answer (score 0):

You want to start by checking the physical SQL which is written to the nqquery.log. It can also be obtained by viewing the log in Answers directly. Another way is to go to Administration > Issue SQL, enable presentation server cache, set the debug level to 7, execute the SQL and click on the view log link. The Physical SQl can also be tested against the actual database, if that is where your data is coming from. Examining both - your Logical SQL and your Physical SQL can resolve a lot of minor issues, including this one.